# python: libraries for parsing email

Tags: python, email

Are there libraries for email message parsing (particularly, from Gmail's IMAP server) in Python (except for the standard email library)?

Or if not, maybe there is some C++ library for this purpose (and I'll be able to use it through SWIG)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what's the difference between emails on GMail retrieved via IMAP and any other message?

Comment: I don't think you meant Parsing here? You meant accessing.

Comment: sorry for possible misunderstanding, but i meant exactly "parsing".
Why i don't want to use standard python email library? - we are already using this library in our project, but it is quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

This question does not make sense. You can access GMail either using IMAP or POP3.
And for parsing retrieved emails you use the 'email' module of Python. Python provides support for all this out-of-the-box "all batteries included".

Answer (score 0):

http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/ is a Python bindings to Gmail. Also you have Gdata apis in Python http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gdata/2.0.4 which can help interact with Gmail.

For other stuffs, the standard library module email is good pretty good.
And Email messages are formatted according to RFC2822, a standard library module named `rfc822` and `mimetools` may help you to deal with the contents of the email.

Comment: You want to use IMAP/SMTP to interact with Gmail, not a library like libgmail that scrapes the web interface..